# Distribution of the division of two Gamma distributions.

Tags: probability, gamma-distribution

Let $X \sim \Gamma(k,\theta)$ and Y $\sim \Gamma(p,\theta)$

What is the distribution of $Z = \dfrac{X}{X+Y}$

I know that there are some similar questions here on Stack, but these questions are related to the case when the Gammas are independent and the result is a Beta Prime Distribution, but in this case I cannot simply sum the two Gammas on the denominator and use this kind of result.

I tried to do the Jacobian method, but I struggled to find the joint distribution of X and Y and ended up with a big expression that didn't seems to be correct.

Comment: Presumably $X$ and $Y$ are supposed to be independent.  And note $\dfrac{X}{X+Y} = \dfrac{1}{1+\frac YX}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $z\in(0,1)$. Then,
\begin{align*}
  F_Z(z) = \mathbb P(Z\le z) = \mathbb P(X \le z(X+Y)) = \mathbb P\!\left(\frac{X}{Y} \le \frac{z}{1-z}\right).
\end{align*}
Now use the fact that $X/Y$ follows a [Beta Prime Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_prime_distribution#Related_distributions).